# TreeView : Change Plus Minus icon

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tree, treeview

How do i change the **Plus Minus** icon of **TreeView Control** to some other icon using **C#.Net**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change my treeView icons insted of +,- like a windows explorer treeview in c#.net win forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625420/how-to-change-my-treeview-icons-insted-of-like-a-windows-explorer-treeview-i)

Answer (score 12):

When you want to customize your TreeView control, Microsoft provides a property named `TreeViewDrawMode` on the TreeView control, its value is an enum which has 3 values: `Normal`, `OwnerDrawText`, `OwnerDrawAll`, in your situation, you must use `OwnerDrawAll`.

After you set that property to `TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll`, when the TreeView's nodes are showing, an event named `DrawNode` will be triggered, so you can process your drawing there. When you draw it by yourself, usually you need to draw 3 things: expand/collapse icon, node icon, node text.

My sample is below:

```
//define the icon file path
string minusPath = Application.StartupPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "minus.png";
string plusPath = Application.StartupPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "plus.png";
string nodePath = Application.StartupPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "directory.png";

public FrmTreeView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //setting to customer draw
    this.treeView1.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll;
    this.treeView1.DrawNode += new DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(treeView1_DrawNode);
}

void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle nodeRect = e.Node.Bounds;

    /*--------- 1. draw expand/collapse icon ---------*/
    Point ptExpand = new Point(nodeRect.Location.X - 20, nodeRect.Location.Y + 2);
    Image expandImg = null;
    if (e.Node.IsExpanded || e.Node.Nodes.Count < 1)
        expandImg = Image.FromFile(minusPath);
    else
        expandImg = Image.FromFile(plusPath);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(expandImg);
    IntPtr imgPtr = g.GetHdc();
    g.ReleaseHdc();
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(expandImg, ptExpand);

    /*--------- 2. draw node icon ---------*/
    Point ptNodeIcon = new Point(nodeRect.Location.X - 4, nodeRect.Location.Y + 2);
    Image nodeImg = Image.FromFile(nodePath);
    g = Graphics.FromImage(nodeImg);
    imgPtr = g.GetHdc();
    g.ReleaseHdc();
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(nodeImg, ptNodeIcon);

    /*--------- 3. draw node text ---------*/
    Font nodeFont = e.Node.NodeFont;
    if (nodeFont == null)
        nodeFont = ((TreeView)sender).Font;
    Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
    //to highlight the text when selected
    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Focused) != 0)
        textBrush = SystemBrushes.HotTrack;
    //Inflate to not be cut
    Rectangle textRect = nodeRect;
    //need to extend node rect
    textRect.Width += 40;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, nodeFont, textBrush, 
        Rectangle.Inflate(textRect, -12, 0));
}
```

[image: the result of my test]

Comment: when I expand treeview it render text from root node also

Comment: hi Vignesh, I guess that you need to adjust the location point of text.

Comment: I tried the above sample code .but its cause an error for me. if I click any node .it will draw on that  node location and also draw on first root node. I want to stop the child node was draw on first root node. this is my output screen https://s1.postimg.org/84fhr5dnf3/treeview.png

Comment: hi Vignesh, sorry for late response, I guess you already figured it out, if not, please give me your code by a link or mail.

Comment: if (e.Node.Bounds.X != 0 )
   {    //Drawnode logic write inside this condition  then its works good            }

Comment: Thank you for the example. One minor point - It needs to be updated to dispose of the graphics resources. Otherwise there will be memory leaks.